# References in Java with image

Tags: java, c++

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * } 
 */

          ListNode newNode = null;
          ListNode nxt = head.next;
          head.next = newNode; <--- CONFUSION
          newNode = head;
          head = nxt;
```

[image]

**The above image** is before we do `head.next = newNode`

So when we do that:

[image]

In this case, tell me if I am right please:

You change what head.next points to and `nxt` remains the same since we referenced it to the old `head.next` before.

**Confirm:**

The way `ListNode head` works in Java is the same as `ListNode * head` would work in C/C++?

Comment: `newNode` has the value `null` (it doesn't refer to anything) and thus assigning it to `head.next` will make `head.next` have the value `null` as well.

Comment: Why the c++ tag?

Comment: Think of ``curr.next`` as the member(variable) of curr which stores the reference to next of curr.

Comment: @YSC, look at the last line in my question

Comment: @Thomas, how about the **confirm** in my question

Comment: Unless you elaborate on that "question" (and add a please ;) ) I'm inclined to say "no, they don't the same - they are similar but Java references are not (mere) pointers (there is no pointer arithmetic on them, the targets can be moved around in memory etc.)".

Comment: @Thomas, if I say please, does that change the answer? :) Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's references are *kind of* like pointers in C++, but they're not the same.
A Java reference refers to a particular class instance (whose location may change), while a C++ pointer refers to a particular location (whose contents can be replaced with a different object).

In this particular case, the differences don't matter much; they are both a form of *indirection*, which is the important part here.

You'll get a clearer picture if you draw the entire nodes, not just their elements.

Something like this (`X` is a null reference)

```
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
| 1 | -----> | 2 | -----> | 3 | -----> | 4 | X |
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
  ^            ^
  |            |
 head         nxt

head.next = newNode:
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
| 1 | X |    | 2 | -----> | 3 | -----> | 4 | X |
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
  ^            ^
  |            |
 head         nxt

newNode = head:        
 newNode
  |
  v
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
| 1 | X |    | 2 | -----> | 3 | -----> | 4 | X |
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
  ^            ^
  |            |
 head         nxt

head = nxt:
 newNode      head
  |            |
  v            v
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
| 1 | X |    | 2 | -----> | 3 | -----> | 4 | X |
+---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+    +---+---+
               ^
               |
              nxt
```

As you can see, the code unlinks the first element of the list, so the name "newNode" isn't very good.

Comment: Amazing answer, very very helpful. I've screen shotted this.